Static pressure calculations for laser fume extration
I'm trying to estimate the static pressure (SP) of a exhaust system for a laser cutter in order to select an appropriate exhaust fan. From what I've read so far (https://www.centralblower.com/Pdf/Determining-Static-Pressure.pdf), I should be able to estimate the SP with tables by selecting a target CFM, and calculating loss associated with each elbow and length of hose of a specific diameter. Should this calculation include hose/ducting before and after the blower or should it only include those sections after the blower?

you are getting the head loss of the exhaust portion.  If the inlet is a closed area and draws a vacuum all the pressure levels will be reduced by that vacuum level.

I would say before and after, the blower is doing work to overcome the losses.

On a high power fan (ex Boiler FD fan) you would calculate the outlet and inlet losses separately since the pressure inside the housing of the fan affects its performance characteristics.
Since this is obviously a less critical analysis you can simply lump the line losses together into a single calculation. You can add say 5% more to the safety factor to cover you. Also, if you are not at sea level you will want to add a bit of safety factor as well. Also add some safety factor if the air temperature will be warmer than room temperature. Temperature and altitude reduce the density of the air and the performance of the fan.
If the exhaust has dust or chemicals that can precipitate on the walls make sure the fan and duct can be dismantled to be periodically cleaned. Or add some additional safety factor to be able to add screen or filter in the future if needed. When in doubt always go larger on an exhaust fan. No one will ever check or complain about the power bill, but they will definitely be upset if not all the exhaust is removed ;-)
